Update property after changes linked to another property and a static value
Here is an example with a simple code:
 public class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
 {
     public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
     //  ...

     // All items have the same bonus
     public static int bonus_sell = 0;

     // The price from the NPC, no problem with this display
     public int VendorValue
     {
           get { return vendorvalue; }
           set { vendorvalue = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
     }

     private int vendorvalue;

     // This is the final price, calculated from one property and the static variable
     // This one is correctly displayed only at the beginning
     public int FinalPrice
     {
           get { return VendorValue+bonussell; }
     }
 }

The final price is just the VendorPrice + the bonus sell.
If VendorValue changes, the FinalPrice displayed (WPF binding) is not updated.
If I change bonus_sell, the FinalPrice is not displayed too.
How can I trigger the FinalPrice "change" when one of its components changes?

It may just be your over simplified example. But, if this is a sample of your ViewModel, then I think it should implement INotifyPropertyChanged Interface. Each property you want to update on the view should raise the event INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged Event

@JayV My real code implement the interface, you can see it with OnPropertyChanged() in VendorValue set. My problem is with FinalPrice that doesn't have setter so it don't raise any event when it's value should be edited when bonus_sell change for example.

You can still raise the event NotifyPropertyChanged by passing a property name to it such as NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(FinalPrice)). Put this in the setter for VendorValue, or any other sensible place in your code

@JayV So I have no choice to do it manually for each "component", there is no way to automatically link the FinalPrice update to the variable/properties it is calculed from?

Correct. each notification you want has to be raised separately. You can simplify the code by using helper functions that take in a list of property names

Ty for your explanations. I have post an anwser according to it.

As specified by JayV, I have to notify the property change manually.
public class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    //  ...
    
    // All items have the same bonus
    private static int bonus_sell = 0;

    // The price from the NPC, no problem with this display
    public int VendorValue
    {
        get { return vendorvalue; }
        set { 
            vendorvalue = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(); OnPropertyChanged("FinalPrice");
        }
    }
    private int vendorvalue;

    // This is the final price, calculated from one property and the static variable
    // This one is correctly displayed only at the beginning
    public int FinalPrice
    {
        get { return VendorValue+bonussell; }
    }

    public void Set_Bonus_Sell(int value)
    {
        bonus_sell=value;
        OnPropertyChanged("FinalPrice");
    }
}


Okay, but use nameof(FinalPrice). The compiler will check the name and the rename refactoring will also include the nameof parameter.

Your self-answer is the vanilla way of doing it, and there's nothing wrong with it. Except for the fact it's extremely verbose and annoying when you have hundreds of objects and properties.
Luckily we're blessed with source generators in dotnet, which can hook into the compiler and generate boring stuff automatically. One of them is the magical PropertyChanged.Fody. You can add it to your project using NuGet.
It will generate property notifications for all your public properties -- and their dependent properties. E.g.:
[AddINotifyPropertyChangedInterface] // <- Magic!
public class Item
{
  // Get-only property dependent on another.
  // Will be triggered when VendorValue changes:
  public int FinalPrice => VendorValue * 1.5; // 50% mark-up. I'm a good salesperson.

  // This will automatically trigger PropertyChanged
  // for BOTH FinalPrice & VendorValue:
  public int VendorValue { get; set; };  
}

Your static field presents some complications, but you can do half-manual, half-automatic notifications:
public class Item: INotifyPropertyChanged // Manual declaration and implementation
{
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
  protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string? propertyName = null)
    => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

  public int VendorValue { get; set; } // Auto trigger
  public int FinalPrice => VendorValue + bonus; // Auto triggered by VendorValue

  private static int bonus = 10;
  public void SetBonus(int val)
  {
    bonus = val;
    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FinalPrice)); // Manual trigger
  }
}


The problem is that this only updates one instance, but updating the bonus affects all instances, e.g. in a DataGridView.

@OlivierJacot-Descombes Fair point. I was just presenting an alternative to manually implementing INotifyPropertyChanged, by using code generation/weaving instead. As for OP, making static properties update all instances should be implemented with a static Event, e.g. like this.
